# How to create relationships with Django

Tags: django, database, model, psql

Say I have two tables: `TableOne` and `TableTwo`. In both tables I have the same column `column_name`. The relationships are as follows:

1. `TableOne` has `zero-to-many` of `TableTwo`
2. `TableTwo` belongs to `one-to-many` of `TableOne`

The `column_name` I mentioned before is shared between (same) for both `TableOne` and `TableTwo`. So I believe I should just make this into its own table, `TableThree`, where `TableThree` will have foreign keys `table_one_id` and `table_two_id`, plus other columns that aren't important for this question.

The relationship will be as follows:

1. `TableOne` has `zero-to-many` of `TableThree`
2. `TableThree` belongs to `one-to-many` of `TableOne`
3. `TableTwo` belongs to `zero-to-many` of `TableThree`
4. `TableThree` belongs to `one-to-many` of `TableTwo`

I can update my question to be better explained if needed. I'm quite new to databases so I'm not sure if I'm making the right design here but if I am I would like to know how to represent this in my `Django models`.

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class PetOwner(models.Model):
    """Model representing a pet owner."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Enter owner's first name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Enter owner's last name")
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True, help_text="Enter owner's email"
    )
    address = models.CharField(
        max_length=240, blank=True, help_text="Enter owner's address"
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=15, blank=True, unique=True, help_text="Enter owner's phone number"
    )

    class Meta:
        """Controls default ordering of records when querying the Model type."""

        ordering = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record of this pet owner."""
        return reverse("petowner_detail", args=[str(self.id)])


class Pet(models.Model):
    """Model representing a pet."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Enter pet's first name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Enter pet's last name")
    breeds = models.ManyToManyField("Breed", help_text="Select a breed for this pet")
    weight = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, help_text="Enter pet's weight"
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField("Died", null=True, blank=True)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(PetOwner, help_text="Select an owner for this pet")

    class Meta:
        """Controls the default ordering of records when querying the Model type."""

        ordering = ["last_name", "first_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this pet."""
        return reverse("pet_detail", args=[str(self.id)])

    def display_owner(self):
        """Create a string for the PetOwner. This is required to display owner in Admin."""
        return ", ".join(owner.first_name for owner in self.owners.all()[:3])

    def display_breed(self):
        """Create a string for the Breed. This is required to display breed in Admin."""
        return ", ".join(breed.name for breed in self.breeds.all()[:3])

    display_owner.short_description = "Parent"


class Breed(models.Model):
    """Model representing a pet breed"""

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, help_text="Enter a pet breed (e.g. Golden Retriever)"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.name
```

There is some extra stuff that is not necessary for this post in the code I included but it should be quite easy to follow I think.

What I want is to abstract `address` field from both `PetOwner` and `Pet` (notice I forgot to add it for `Pet`) and turn it into it's own table and have `PetOwner` and `Pet` referenced in `Address` table.

I ended up making the following changes...

```
# in Pet added field
address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

# PetOwner added field
address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

# created Address table
class Address(models.Model):
    home_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, help_text="Enter your house/Apt/Unit number"
    )
    street = models.CharField(max_length=15, help_text="Enter your street")
    town = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Enter your county/town")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Enter your state")
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Enter your zipcode")
```

I'm not sure how to test if this resolves my issue.

Comment: what you have tried ? Can you share your code ?

Comment: Yes, I added my code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a PET is ONE BREED. And a PET has ONE OWNER (arguably).
Hence from PET a `ForeignKey` to BREED and one to OWNER.

Since it is unlikely, that the PET has a different address than the owner (again arguably :)), I'd suggest that only the OWNER has a link to ADDRESS.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to keep the current setup I have for the things you mentioned. As a family we can see both parents being owners and even maybe the children as well. I'm going to be building this out to be a bigger application than it is now that `vets` will be able to access and a `PetOwner` will have a field specifying if they are permitted to make more important decisions. Maybe I can have a `CoOwner` table that with a one-to-one relationship for this? Either way what I am wondering is if I have my `Address` correct with what I want to achieve.